# What is the fastest way to delete an element of an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, optimization

Giving this array:

```
arr=(hello asd asd1 asd22 asd333)
```

I want to delete the a especific item by its value, for example `asd`. I did this:

```
IFS=' '
echo "${arr[@]/asd/}"
```

But it returns the following:

hello  1 22 333

So I did this function:

```
function remove_item() {
    local item_search="$1"
    shift
    local arr_tmp=("${@}")

    if [ ${#arr_tmp[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        return
    fi

    local index=0
    for item in ${arr_tmp[@]}; do
        if [ "$item" = "$item_search" ]; then
            unset arr_tmp[$index]
            break
        fi
        let index++
    done

    echo "${arr_tmp[*]}"
}

arr=(asd asd1 asd22 asd333)

remove_item 'asd' "${arr[@]}"
```

Prints the desired output:

```
hello asd1 asd22 asd333
```

But I have to use it with very long arrays, and I have to call it a lot of times. And its performance sucks.

Do you have any better alternative to do it? Any tip, trick, or advice will be appreciatted.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, first you say that you want to delete the first item (i.e. delete by index) but the function you wrote deletes by value. So which is the goal? If the latter, you could use associative arrays if you have bash v>=4 and you wouldn't have to do the iteration.

Comment: Sorry. Post edited! I want to remove it by value. :) Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use bash?  Probably *every* other language will have better performance on "very long arrays".

Comment: Yes, I have a long program to modify. And I won't translate all it to another language. I'm looking for an efficient way to do it. If is on little better, is ok. Thanks

Comment: Re "and I have to call it a lot of times", Does that mean you are deleting many items from one array, or does that mean you are deleting items from many arrays?

Comment: I'm afraid on different arrays, dude.

Comment: What about `echo "${arr[@]/%asd/}"`. It works for your given example. `%` says to match at the end of the string.

Comment: Is the input really an array, or is the previous step to create the array from something else?

Comment: Do you need the array to be reindexed, or should the indexing remain the same, with a hole where the unset element used to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop to iterate over the array and remove the element that matches the specified value:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
  [[ "${arr[i]}" == "asd" ]] && unset arr[i]
done
```

If you know that the array would have at most one matching element, you could even `break` out of the loop:

```
  [[ "${arr[i]}" == "asd" ]] && unset arr[i] && break
                                            |^^^^^^^^|
                                             (this causes the loop to break
                                              as soon as the element is found)
```

---

As an example:

```
$ arr=(asd asd1 asd22 asd333)
$ for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do [[ "${arr[i]}" == "asd" ]] && unset arr[i]; done
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
asd1 asd22 asd333
```

Comment: But this code will be loop until the end of the array. And mine breaks at eh first match. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnDoe If you use the line with `break`, then it'd _break_ at the first match.

Comment: I know. I mean, my function breaks at the first occurrence, and yours not. Then, I think mine would be most efficient, dont you think?

Comment: @JohnDoe I assume that you didn't understand the `break` part.  Refer to the edit above, I've added an explanation.  If you use the line containing `break` instead in the loop, then it breaks as soon as the element is found.

Comment: haha, sorry. I didn't realice you had edited the post. Thanks for all, @devnull. All is clear now. :)

Comment: @JohnDoe I added the pictorial explanation now, but the `break` part existed in the original answer `:)`

Comment: I have to renew my glasses.

Answer (score 1):

Probably @devnull's answer is fastest.  But it might possibly be faster not to use a loop and instead let `grep` do the work.  Its not very pretty though:

```
$ arr=(hello asd asd1 asd22 asd333)
$ remove="asd"
$ i=$(paste -d: <(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}") | grep -m1 -w -E "^[[:digit:]]+:${remove}$")
$ unset arr[${i%:*}]
$
```